# How does Libreoffice store remembered passwords for network shares?

Tags: networking, password, security, libreoffice

I'm opening files from a remote network share in Libreoffice.  I have to enter my password in the following dialog:

[image: libreoffice authentication dialog]

There's the option "Remember password". If I used that option, where would the password be stored? Would it be stored unencrypted or does it use something like Gnome keyring?

Comment: Quite likely this is not LibreOffice but ssh.